# Is it possible to hard declare a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, analytics, declaration

I am trying to use a variable inside a substructure. I guess the variable should be of integer data type, and I am trying to add a loop here but it my data type is list since it contains multiple integers.

```
INV_match_id = [['3749052'],['3749522']]
from statsbombpy import sb
for x in range(2):
   match=INV_match_id[x]
   match_db = sb.events(match_id=match)
   print(match)
```

I have tried to extract the data one by one using another variable, but still it got declared as list. Whenever I give direct values to "match" it works. for eg: if I add a line match=12546 the substructure takes the value properly.

Next thing I want to try is hard declare "match" variable as integer. Any input is appreciated. I am pretty new to Python.

Edit: Adding this solution from @quamrana here.
"So, to answer your original question: Is it possible to hard declare a variable in Python?, the answer is No. Variables in python are just references to objects. Objects can be of whatever type they want to be."

Comment: The result of a list comprehension is, of cause, a list. What was your expectation?

Comment: @KlausD. I want to take out a single number from the list and that as an integer. is it possible to do that?

Comment: Which number did you want? How many numbers are there in your list?

Comment: We'll have retrieve an item from a list by index exactly one line before. So you know how to do that.

Comment: @quamrana I want to loop and take the numbers one by one. there are like 30 numbers inside the "INV_match_id" list.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, that part I know. the problem is when I take out a single number, that single number is also declared as a list. like this- ['125364']

Comment: When asking a question, make sure you're providing a [mre] -- code someone else can run *without changes* to get the **exact same error**. We have no way of knowing what the results of these operations will be if we don't know what the input data is, so for answers to be testable, you should be referring only to variables that are themselves defined within the question. (Mind, you should be making those definitions as short as possible -- don't provide 30 values if it only takes 2 to show the problem -- but the code given in the question needs to be runnable on its own).

Comment: It seems likely that your input is a list of lists, not a list of strings, but right now we're having to guess. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Anyhow -- if Python _did_ support strong, static typing ("variable X can only store an int"), that would just change a runtime error to a compile-time error, it wouldn't mean you'd suddenly have no error at all. The right place to focus is on the data structure and what needs to happen to get an integer out of it; the changes you'd need to make would be the same even if the language _did_ support static typing. So don't ask about how to do static typing -- instead, give us enough information to understand your existing data format, and ask how to get your desired format out of it.

Comment: (If you don't understand your data's current format, `print(repr(...))` is your friend).

Comment: `INV_match_id[x]` is **not** a list, with `INV_match_id` provided the way you give it in the question. If your actual behavior differs, I strongly suggest double-checking the accuracy of the question's code. Mind, it's possible to iterate over a str as if it were a list, but that would be a mistake unless you want to treat `'3749052'` like it were `['3','7','4','9','0','5','2']`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the inputs. I am trying to fix the issue with these inputs. Also, I have updated the code to a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm trying to run your reproducer. That said, installing statsbombpy is being a bit tricky (nixpkgs doesn't have it packaged).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have updated the code just now. the reproducible example I gave was wrong. I was reading the "INV_match_id" from a csv file. and as you said earlier it was becoming a list of lists.

Comment: Ahh! Then you want `[int(i[0]) for i in match]`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes this one worked. Thanks a lot for all the inputs from everyone!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said: `" I want to loop and take the numbers one by one."`

Did you mean this:

```py
for match in INV_match_id:
   match_db = sb.events(match_id=match)
```

I don't know what you want to do with `match_db`

Update:

`"that single number is also declared as a list. like this- ['125364']"`

Well if `match == ['125364']` then it depends on whether you want: `"125364"` or `125364`. I assume the latter since you talk a lot about integers:

```py
for match in INV_match_id:
   match = int(match[0])
   match_db = sb.events(match_id=match)
```

Next Update:

So you have: `INV_match_id = ['3749052','3749522']`

This means that the list is a list of strings, so the code changes to this:

```py
for match in INV_match_id:
   match_db = sb.events(match_id=int(match))
```

Your original code was making `match` into a list of the digits of each number. (eg `match = [1,2,5,3,6,4]`)

Reversionary Update:

This time we have: `INV_match_id = [['3749052'],['3749522']]`

that just means going back to the second version of my code above:

```py
for match in INV_match_id:
   match = int(match[0])
   match_db = sb.events(match_id=match)
```

Comment: ['125364']
still the match variable is coming as a list.

Comment: You need to update your question with a small sample of the data in `INV_match_id`. Otherwise we are guessing the length of a piece of string.

Comment: sorry for the mess up. actually I was reading the "INV_match_id" from a csv file. so it was a list of lists. [['3749052'], ['3749522']] etc. I have updated the code like that

Comment: So, to answer your original question: `Is it possible to hard declare a variable in Python?`, the answer is No. Variables in python are just references to objects. Objects can be of whatever type they want to be.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
from statsbombpy import sb
INV_match_id = [['3749052'],['3749522']]
for e in INV_match_id:
   match_db = sb.events(match_id=e[0])
   print(match_db)
```

You have a list of lists albeit that the sub-lists only contain one item.

match_id can be either a string or int